# Traer el resultado de dos consultas a mysql a lista select de formulario y posicionar lo seleccionado

Tags: php, html-select

El problema que quiero solucionar es el siguiente: dispongo de un formulario en forma de tabla dinámica en el cual recojo los datos de la B.D llamando a dos tablas Cod_Menu_Socios y Menus_Socios . Los datos de la primera tabla los recojo en una lista desplegable sin mayor problema y el usuario puede selecciona una de las opciones la cual se guarda en la tabla de Menus_Socios. El problema es que si el usuario quiere modificar o cambiar su selección, no le aparece la opción elegida por defecto en la caja de texto del desplegable aunque si la desplegamos, aparece como si formara parte de una opción mas.
[image: Esta es lo que se ve antes de desplegar la caja de opciones]
[image: Esto es cuando desplegamos. La opción elegida por el usuario es la de arriba].

La pregunta es: ¿Cómo hago para que cuando cargue el formulario me aparezca antes de desplegar la caja de texto, la opción elegida esto es, en el ejemplo, Sopa de Marisco. Dejo el código.

```html
<html>

   <?php for ($i=1; $i<=$tdias; $i++) {  ?>
<?php
$dnisoc=$rowSocio["dni"];
// ----------Primeros Platos -------------------
  $sqlGes1 = "SELECT * FROM Cod_Menus_Socios   
           WHERE numconv = '$numconv'
           and situacPlato= 'A' and dia='$i' and numplato='1' "; 
        $result1=mysqli_query($con,$sqlGes1);

// ---------- Menús seleccionados--------------
 $sqlGes4 = "SELECT * FROM Menus_Socios
           WHERE numconv = '$numconv'
           and dni= '$dnisoc' and dia='$i' ";
        $result4=mysqli_query($con,$sqlGes4); 
?>        

             <tbody>
        <tr class="headt">


<td><div class="size"><input id="dia0" style=" height: 26px;" class="dia"  type=text  name="dia[]" value="<?php echo $i; ?>"</div>
</td>

<td><div class="size3">

    <?php
   while($rowGes4=mysqli_fetch_array($result4)) 
     {
    ?>

<Select id="primerPlato0" style=" width: 250px; height: 26px;" class="primerPlato"  type="text" name=primerPlato[]  >

<option value="">  <?php echo $rowGes4['plato_01']; ?></option>
 

<option value=" "selected> A Elegir..</option>

       <?php while($rowGes1=mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){ ?>

<option value="<?php echo $rowGes1['descripcion']; ?>" <?php if($rowGes1['descripcion']==$descripcion) { echo 'selected'; } ?>>

       <?php echo $rowGes1['descripcion']; ?> </option><?php } ?>
                                        
  
    <?php }?>                              
</select></div>
</td>

 
         </tr>
   <?php  ?>   
<?php } ?> 
  
                </tbody>
</html>
```

Comment: Si guiones mantener los datos es preferible que uses el localstorage para almacenar el dato y luego recuperarlo

Comment: ¿Puedes ser mas explicito ?

Answer (score 0):

intentare explicarme...
Yo le daria un valor a cada opcion del select, que entiendo se llena con datos de la bbdd y colocaria un id_plato... Luego consulto si alguna de mis opciones el id coincide con el de la consulta, y si es asi, que muestre esta en el select... asi:
´´´´

<option
value="0"

>Seleccione:

```
                           <?php                                    
                           $sql = "SELECT * FROM Menus_Socios"; //aqui la consulta para llenar el select donde estan todos los platos con su id_plato
                           $platos = mysqli_query($db, $sql);   
                           if(!empty($platos)):
                           while($resultado= mysqli_fetch_assoc($platos)):
                           ?>
                            <option 
                                id="platos_menu" 
                                value="<?=$resultado['Id_plato']?>"
                                <?=(isset($rowGes4['Id_plato']) && $rowGes4['Id_plato'] == $resultado['Id_plato'])  ? 'selected' :'' ?> 
                            ><?=$resultado['plato']?> 
                            </option>
                            <?php 
                            endwhile;
                            endif;
                            ?>
                        </select>
```

```
No se si he sabido explicarme bien, si no es asi... consulta nuevamente tus dudas...
```